# Engineering rendering for catalog

Tags: rendering

I have and assignment in work where I have to render certain mechanical components for book, the problem is they aren't realistic.

I can't share the picture I have as a reference, but basicaly it has only few things going on that I have no idea how to accomplish in blender (or any other software that I know of)

The render is as follow:

Assembly of few parts floating in space of white background.

Part of the shell is made transparent so you could see insides of the mechanism

Everything is greyscale with few parts colored differently to stand out.

Light could be seen on parts only as gradient from one side to the other. (no shart reflections or anything like that)

Any pointers would be highly appreciated, as I don't even know if this is achievable in blender.

Comment: Everything you’ve listed can be done in Blender, but as a question this is too broad to answer.  Try choosing something specific that you’re having trouble with and you’ll probably have more luck here.

Comment: Doesn't look so difficult to do, but what are you asking exactly? If you don't ask help on a precise point, it is difficult to give you a precise answer. The part of the shell made transparent could be done with a boolean modifier to split the shell in parts and apply different materials on each part, for the rest, it is juste about composing and texturing, and there are tons of tutorial about that everywhere.

Comment: The main problems for me at the moment is that there is no texture on components (it doesn't look like diffuse, but doesn't look like glossy either) the light just looks like gradient from one side of the part to the other.

Answer (score 1):

In Cycles create your objects and assign simple Diffuse BDSF shaders to them. Add a plane for the background and add a white Diffuse BDSF shader (If it's not white enough depending on your lighting change it to an Emission shader). Create your "Shell" and give it a Diffuse BDSF and Transparent shader controlling the transparency with a Mix shader.

Objects:

[image: Objects]

Node set up for shell:

[image: Nodes]

Result:

[image: Result]